# Missing getDirectRawImageRemote() in NAOqi ver. 2.8.6.23

Tags: nao-robot

After porting from NAOqi ver. 2.8.5.10 to 2.8.6.23 I have found that:

```
std::string ALVideoDeviceProxy::subscribe()
```

is missing, which is not so suspicious, because it was already deprecated and could be replaced with:

```
std::string ALVideoDeviceProxy::subscribeCamera()
```

but also:

```
AL::ALValue ALVideoDeviceProxy::getDirectRawImageRemote()
```

is missing, and has to be replaced with:

```
AL::ALValue ALVideoDeviceProxy::getImageRemote()
```

Is it correct and does it have any impact on the performance?

Answer (score 1):

Some API have been removed and the documentation will be updated accordingly.

Yes, you can use `getImageRemote` instead of `getDirectRawImageRemote`.
There is no performance impact if there is only one subscriber or multiple subscribers using same resolution natively supported and colour space (`kYUV422ColorSpace`). In this case there no resizing or colour space conversion.